# How to set the Default chinese version in localized app for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

There are 2 version chinese , there are 1) Simplified 2) Traditional and there are at least 3 sub version under these 2 which are  Taiwan chinese, Singapore Chinese, Hong Kong Chinese.

I have create  resource files for simplified chinese, japanese, Korea. And My App work for main Simplified chinese and sub version republic of china

The problem:
resource.zh-CN.resx contains simplified Chinese character.

1) If user from Hong Kong set Display format: Traditional and region format :Hong Kong chinese. My app has problem to display. The same if user from taiwan set up Display Format :Traditional and Region Format: Taiwan chinese.

Any1 experience this?

2) How to inform user to use Display format: Simplified Chinese? If the system detect you select traditional and  resource file contains simplified chinese, it will display english!!

-1-- Update :

fact : There is only one language code for chinese : zh-CN
       Only one resource format for chinese . example : resource.zh-CN.resx

-2--- Update

Look at the emulator. Goto Settings and select region ad Language.

select 1)) Display Chinese

```
   2) This is the sub version of chinese. </br>
```

-3-- Update:

How Do I create resources file for Chinese? Is this the only format ? Ie Resource.zh-CN.resx?

In setting (in the phone or emulator), It has Display format : Simplified and Traditional.

If only one resource for a language, how can it contains both simplified and traditional characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can offer a settings menu and let the user explicit set a desired culture. In the app constructor (befor InitializeComponent) you set the CurrentUICulture property of the current thread to the desired culture. With this you set the culture to load the UI strings etc.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(preferedCultureString)
```

If formatting of dates, numbers etc. differes between the cultures then set CurrentCulture also.

Comment: I dont get it. See the above. There is only one language code : zh-CN. How do I set it for example simplified and Taiwan chinese? Please show example. Thanks

Comment: Do you use Wp 7.0 or Mango? Mango adds many new cultures - for Chinease the following cultures are working on the current dev tools and can be selected in the settings to:

    cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-HK"));
    cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-CN"));
    cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-MO"));
    cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-SG"));
    cultures.Add(new CultureInfo("zh-TW"));

Comment: I have found an interesting blog post to this topic: http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/supported-cultures-in-windows-phone-7.html

Comment: Hi, I m using WP SDK7.1 RC and Mango Emulator. U are right, there are many version of chinese. Now problems are identified. 1) resource file has to be resource.zh-CN.resx 2) How system tell if this resource file contain simplified character or traditional character? When my resource file contain simplified character and in setting I select Display format: Traditional. It wont work. So, question is How do I create 2 version of resource files ? one contains simplified char and the other contains traditional char?

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you updated your supported cultures in the csproj-file?

Comment: Hi, I did add the Supported Cultures : zh-CN;jp-JP;ko-KR  still not working. Any hints

Answer (score 0):

System Locale have both Hong Kong, Macao, PRC, Signapore and Taiwan as supported english languages.

While the overall system language only have one version of Chinese (I think, I can't read Chinese graphic character), you can simply set the Culture to the UI Culture, which would use the System Locale, supporting several versions of Chinese.

This is done by

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: Hi, Display format and region format are quite different. Let say, I have a resource file for chinese: resource.zh-CN.resx and it contains simplified characters. Now, in settings, if I select Display format :Traditional and region :Chiinese (PRC), it wont work. It work if select Display :Simplified. How system KNOWS the resource file contains Simplified or Traditional character??